# Error: `x` must be a string or a R connection

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a question regarding the proper usage of aes_string()
some.data is a data frame that contains a column named 'x'.

```
print(some.data)
print(some.data$x)
p=  ggplot()+
    geom_raster(data=reshape2::melt(d), aes_string(x="Var1",y="Var2",fill="value"),interpolate=FALSE)+
    scale_fill_gradient(low = "black", high = "white")+ guides(fill=FALSE)+
    geom_path(data=some.data,
              aes_string(x="x", y="y",group="indexPerFile", color = shQuote(color)))+
```

The Traceback shows that the problem was in the last line and the Error message was

```
Error: `x` must be a string or a R connection
```

should aes_string be used within a different function?

Comment: According to [this](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ggplot2/versions/1.0.0/topics/aes_string) aes_string is not to be used within `geom_path`.
Provide a minimal working example with some data to get more precise answers. Also, what is your variable `d`?

Comment: changing aes_string to aes resolved the issue. Thank you!